How to redirect a request to an existing S3 object having the `s3.amazonaws.com` urls
I had created a bucket to store customer images on S3 quite some time ago. Our customer emails contain s3 urls of the format
https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucketName>/<fileName>
so that the customers can download their images if needed. Im planning to move all these objects to a new bucket. But i'm worried that the existing urls sent out in the emails will no longer work. So i've been searching for a way to redirect requests that reference any object in my old bucket.
So far i've only seen solutions for objects that are referenced using the static web endpoint of the bucket (urls that look like the one below).
http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image.png.
I was wondering if there is a way to redirect requests that reference objects through urls like the one mentioned below.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/image.png.
The idea is to potentially redirect to my own endpoint where I can serve the file depending on where it’s been moved to.

Redirects can go to any url.

Yes, but how do can we configure that on s3. Lets say someone tries to access https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/image.png. I want it to get redirected to a custom endpoint.

Have you googled 'S3 redirect' and read some documentation? If no, please do. If yes, share where you got stuck with this.

I have gone through documentation provided by amazon here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html . They only seem to be talking about redirects for buckets with static web-hosting enabled. This would work for the new s3 urls that i may send out but my old urls will not work.

However i had added the same question to amazon repost where i got some responses im gonna try these out and will post it here if that works.
https://repost.aws/questions/QUONZoADSwQNu5OSzjNvt34Q/how-to-redirect-a-request-to-an-existing-s3-object-having-the-s3-amazonaws-com-urls
